# Pushing to GitHub from within Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I've been trying to figure out why Xcode keeps trying to tell me that my GitHub username is 'git' like shown in the photo.

[image]

The project is already on GitHub, but now when I try to push a new update this keeps happing. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I setup the connection to the repo using SSH. Try changing it to HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks! gonna attempt this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ssh here so change authentication method to `ssh keys` and enter passphrase.